# how to calculate discount and service tax on grand total in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i use want to calculate discount and service tax on grand total in crystal report..

**Item  Quantity    Amount**
abc   1            1000 
xyz   2            5000 
pqr   4            1200

```
Grand Total     7200
Discount     200    
                7000//after calculate discount  
Service Tax  100    
                7100//after calculate Service Tax   
Final Amount    7100
```

Comment: It's not clear for me what do you want to do, please be more specific. Provide some code, tell what have you tried, show some effort.

Comment: I agree with the above, but even your own maths looks wrong `(1 * 1000) + (2 * 5000) + (4 * 1200) - 300 = 15,500`